# How to set up DBI and OBDC in R Docker image to run PSQL queries through DBI?

Tags: r, postgresql, docker, odbc, rodbc

I was trying to find a docker image with R, ODBC and DBI installed and I could not find any. So I created one - `anirbans96/rodbcdbi`

Now, when I am trying to run queries on PostgresSQL using `psqlodbcw.so` as driver, it fails by saying that it couldn't find the driver. However, I copied over this file from `laudio/pyodbc:1.0.38` docker image at `us/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so' to the same location on my Docker Image.

However, when I am initiating a connection using

```
DBI::dbConnect(
    odbc::odbc(),
    Server=server,
    Database=database,
    UID=user,
    PWD=password
)
```

It is throwing the error : `nanodbc/nanodbc.coo:1118: 0000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager] Can't open lib '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so' : file not found`

I verified that the file exists using:

```bash
if test -f "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so"; then
    echo "File Exists"
fi
```

My Dockerfile -

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y build-essential curl gnupg2 software-properties-common dirmngr apt-transport-https apt-utils lsb-release ca-certificates
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev mssql-tools 

# Install R packages (odbc R package must be installed AFTER installing ODBC in the OS)
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('odbc')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('DBI')"

# Copy and execute R script
# RUN mkdir /home/analysis
# COPY transformdata.r /home/analysis/transformdata.r
# CMD R -e "source('/home/analysis/transformdata.r')"
```

This has been pushed as `anirbans96/rodbcdbi`
Dockerfile file where I copied `pysqlodbc.so`:

```
FROM anirbans96/rodbcdbi
RUN mdkir /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/
COPY psqlodbcw.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/psqlodbcw.so
```

What else do we need to configure?

Comment: If you're already building with a local `Dockerfile`, why are you choosing to copy just one `.so` file instead of the preferred method of installing `postgresql-client` and `odbc-postgresql` completely?

Comment: I would go further and _somewhat strongly_ recommend to ditch ODBC and just use one of the several (!!) available packages that connect directly: RPostgreSQL and RPostgres are two of them.  You should also be able to install those as Ubuntu binaries bringing the necessary PostgreSQL run-time library in.

Comment: @Dirk Yes, but I am operating in an environment with shared code and making that change has non-technical hurdles. But I agree.

Comment: @r2evans, I was not sure of what to install. Do you mean installing `postgresql-client` and `odbc-postgresql` via `apt-get`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @[r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)

I add `apt-get odbc-postgresql postgresql-client` and it solved the issue.

The new Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y build-essential curl gnupg2 software-properties-common dirmngr apt-transport-https apt-utils lsb-release ca-certificates odbc-postgresql postgresql-client unixodbc-dev
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('odbc')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('DBI')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('stringr')"
```

This has been added to Dockerhub as the new `anirbans96/rodbcdbi`